How to stop current login [running] script
We bought a system some years ago and we don't have any admin users. When we login to the system (by ssh on puttY), it seems a shell script or a program is running and show us a menu like following
1- System Health Check
2- Save
3- Restart
4- Configuration
0- Exit

All interrupt keys like Ctrl+\ or Ctrl+C are disabled.
My question is, is it possible to stop this running program and get command prompt on this system?

Yes; Only a system administrator can make the appropriate

[How] Can an executable (script or binary) disable all terminal genertaed signla?

What? Can you clarify your question?
